# react native: There is way to fix the check boxes in my example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

1. How can i put all the checkboxes under one view ?
2. How can i make choose all, when i will press it so it will check the all rest check boxes and when i will press it again so it will delete my all checks ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

const App = () => {
  const [isSelected1, setSelection1] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected2, setSelection2] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected1}
          onValueChange={setSelection1}
          style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>CHOOSE ALL</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected2}
          onValueChange={setSelection2}
          style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>THE NAME</Text>      
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  checkboxContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    // marginBottom: 20,
  },
  checkbox: {
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  label: {
    margin: 8,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. if you want your check box text to be align vertically then you can just remove all the checkboxContainer views but if you want to keep your current layout you will need all the checkboxContainer views.
2. I have added a additional checkbox with the helper function which implements the all checked/not checked functionality

```html
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import CheckBox from "@react-native-community/checkbox";

const App = () => {
  const [isSelected1, setSelection1] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected2, setSelection2] = useState(false);

  const checkAllHelper = (value) => {
    if (value) {
      setSelection1(true);
      setSelection2(true);
    } else {
      setSelection1(false);
      setSelection2(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected1}
          onValueChange={setSelection1}
          style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>CHOOSE ALL</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected2}
          onValueChange={setSelection2}
          style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>THE NAME</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected1 && isSelected2}
          onValueChange={(newValue) => checkAllHelper(newValue)}
          style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>Check All CheckBoxes</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  checkboxContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    // marginBottom: 20,
  },
  checkbox: {
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  label: {
    margin: 8,
  },
});

export default App;
```